# Cache::flush() Laravel error: Command 'EXECUTECOMMANDONNODES' is not a registered Redis command

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

We want to clear all the cache at once with an endpoint within laravel.

Using Laravel I am trying to run the `Cache::flush()` function in one of my graphql queries (built on top of rebing/graphql).

I get the following error when hitting that endpoint or running `Cache::flush` on its own.

We are configured to be using redis cache

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "debugMessage": "Command 'EXECUTECOMMANDONNODES' is not a registered Redis command.",
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "internal"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "clearCache"
            ],
            "trace": [
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/predis\/predis\/src\/Client.php",
                    "line": 323,
                    "call": "Predis\\Profile\\RedisProfile::createCommand('EXECUTECOMMANDONNODES', array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/predis\/predis\/src\/Client.php",
                    "line": 314,
                    "call": "Predis\\Client::createCommand('executeCommandOnNodes', array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Redis\/Connections\/PredisClusterConnection.php",
                    "line": 16,
                    "call": "Predis\\Client::__call('executeCommandOnNodes', array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cache\/RedisStore.php",
                    "line": 233,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Redis\\Connections\\PredisClusterConnection::flushdb()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cache\/Repository.php",
                    "line": 674,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Cache\\RedisStore::flush()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cache\/CacheManager.php",
                    "line": 418,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository::__call('flush', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Support\/Facades\/Facade.php",
                    "line": 261,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheManager::__call('flush', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/Library\/RedisCacheManager.php",
                    "line": 62,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('flush', array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/GraphQL\/Mutations\/Core\/ClearCacheMutation.php",
                    "line": 56,
                    "call": "App\\Library\\RedisCacheManager::clearAll()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 237,
                    "call": "App\\GraphQL\\Mutations\\Core\\ClearCacheMutation::resolve(null, array(0), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 150,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(null, array(0), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/Field.php",
                    "line": 149,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 623,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\Field::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\{closure}(null, array(0), instance of App\\User, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 549,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveFieldValueOrError(instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\FieldDefinition, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\FieldNode, instance of Closure, null, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Definition\\ResolveInfo)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 474,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField(GraphQLType: Mutation, null, instance of ArrayObject(1), array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 857,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}(array(0), 'clearCache')"
                },
                {
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}(array(0), 'clearCache')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 847,
                    "function": "array_reduce(array(1), instance of Closure, array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 468,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::promiseReduce(array(1), instance of Closure, array(0))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 263,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFieldsSerially(GraphQLType: Mutation, null, array(0), instance of ArrayObject(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/ReferenceExecutor.php",
                    "line": 215,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeOperation(instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\OperationDefinitionNode, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/Executor\/Executor.php",
                    "line": 156,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::doExecute()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 161,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\Executor::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/webonyx\/graphql-php\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 93,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::promiseToExecute(instance of GraphQL\\Executor\\Promise\\Adapter\\SyncPromiseAdapter, instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/GraphqlExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 32,
                    "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeQuery(instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of GraphQL\\Language\\AST\\DocumentNode, null, instance of App\\User, null, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\GraphqlExecutionMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AddAuthUserContextValueMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 28,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AddAuthUserContextValueMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, instance of App\\User, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AutomaticPersistedQueriesMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 49,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AutomaticPersistedQueriesMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 33,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/ValidateOperationParamsMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 39,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\{closure}('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Support\/ExecutionMiddleware\/AbstractExecutionMiddleware.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\ValidateOperationParamsMiddleware::handle('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\ExecutionMiddleware\\AbstractExecutionMiddleware::resolve(array(5), instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(array(5))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 113,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 157,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::thenReturn()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 140,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeViaMiddleware(array(4), 'v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQL.php",
                    "line": 126,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeAndReturnResult('v1', instance of GraphQL\\Type\\Schema, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams, null, null)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQLController.php",
                    "line": 43,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL::execute('v1', instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\Support\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/Helpers.php",
                    "line": 24,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController::Rebing\\GraphQL\\{closure}(instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/rebing\/graphql-laravel\/src\/GraphQLController.php",
                    "line": 39,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\Helpers::applyEach(instance of Closure, instance of GraphQL\\Server\\OperationParams)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php",
                    "line": 54,
                    "call": "Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController::query(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Laragraph\\Utils\\RequestParser, instance of Illuminate\\Config\\Repository, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQL)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php",
                    "line": 45,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller::callAction('query', array(4))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php",
                    "line": 261,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Rebing\\GraphQL\\GraphQLController, 'query')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php",
                    "line": 205,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::runController()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 721,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::run()"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/ThrottleRequests.php",
                    "line": 127,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Middleware\/ThrottleRequests.php",
                    "line": 58,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests::handleRequest(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, array(1))"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, '500', '1')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Auth\/Middleware\/Authenticate.php",
                    "line": 44,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure, 'api')"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 719,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 698,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRouteWithinStack(instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route, instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 662,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Illuminate\\Routing\\Route)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php",
                    "line": 651,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatchToRoute(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatch(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 128,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/Http\/Middleware\/Cors.php",
                    "line": 19,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\Cors::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/app\/Http\/Middleware\/IdentifyTenant.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\IdentifyTenant::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TransformsRequest.php",
                    "line": 21,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
                    "line": 31,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TransformsRequest.php",
                    "line": 21,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/TrimStrings.php",
                    "line": 40,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/ValidatePostSize.php",
                    "line": 27,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Middleware\/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
                    "line": 86,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/fideloper\/proxy\/src\/TrustProxies.php",
                    "line": 57,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 167,
                    "call": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Pipeline\/Pipeline.php",
                    "line": 103,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 142,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then(instance of Closure)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Http\/Kernel.php",
                    "line": 111,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::sendRequestThroughRouter(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                },
                {
                    "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/public\/index.php",
                    "line": 54,
                    "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::handle(instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "clearCache": null
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's not supported or if there's something else going on.

Looking for ideas on how to resolve this, thanks!

Comment: Did you try googling the error? I found [this](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/719#issuecomment-563981954) (you are using `predis` and it is not maintained anymore for a long time, switch to `phpredis`)